# MYSQL insert data into table2 from table1, provided that table1.value1 is not equal table2.value1

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `dictionary2` (word,verb)
SELECT SUBSTRING(word FROM 2)
FROM `dictionary1`
WHERE `dictionary1`.word LIKE "w%"
```

I have two tables, dictionary1(word) and dictionary2(word,verb).

- I would like to insert into dictionary2, values from dictionary1, where word starts with 'w' and the value is not present in dictionary2.word.
- In the same insert I would like to set the value of dictionary2.verb to 1.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Is your column 'word' unique in dictionary2?

Comment: the word column is not unique. My problem is that how to I insert (word,1) into dictionary2.

Comment: Oke, but I think you will use word as the primary search key in you table. So, I would recommend setting it to unique. That way you won't have to worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
INSERT INTO dictionary2 (word, verb)
SELECT dictionary1.word, 1
FROM
  dictionary1 LEFT JOIN dictionary2
  ON dictionary1.word = dictionary2.word
WHERE
  dictionary1.word LIKE 'w%'
  AND dictionary2.word IS NULL
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6170e1/1).

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about using a join but it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanx for the js fiddle. I never knew is existed. " dictionary1.word LIKE 'w%'
  AND dictionary2.word <> dictionary1.word " is what I edited to make sure no duplicate entries from dictionary1.word

Comment: @OneEyedManIsKingAmongTheBlind I'm joining ON dictionary1.word = dictionary2.word, and I'm using a LEFT JOIN. Using WHERE dictionary2.word IS NULL I'm getting all the rows where the join didn't succeed, which are the words that are present in dictionart1 but not in 2

Comment: @fthiella my solution is now INSERT INTO dictionary2
SELECT SUBSTRING(dictionary1.word FROM 2) , 1
FROM
  dictionary1
WHERE
  dictionary1.word LIKE '-%'
  AND SUBSTRING(dictionary1.word FROM 2) NOT IN (SELECT word from dictionary2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO `dictionary2` (word,verb)
SELECT word, (select @number :=1)
FROM `dictionary1`
WHERE `dictionary1`.word LIKE "t%"
AND `dictionary1`.word NOT IN(SELECT word FROM dictionary2);
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `dictionary2` (
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
word VARCHAR (50),
verb VARCHAR (50)
);

CREATE TABLE `dictionary1` (
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
word VARCHAR (50)
);

INSERT INTO `dictionary2`(word,verb) 
VALUES
('test','test'),
('test1','test1'); 
INSERT INTO `dictionary1`(word) VALUES('test'),('testing1');
```

B.T.W. you can safely change `LIKE "t%"` into `LIKE "w%"` ;-)

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0755/1)